# Shortest smooth paper Möbius Strip

Tags: general-topology, optimization, recreational-mathematics, surfaces

[image]

> I want to make a familiar Möbius strip of width 1 unit satisfying the physical properties of paper. Assume paper is a **ruled surface**, and the strip has to be **smooth** and **non-self-intersecting**. What is the shortest length of paper needed to do this?

I know if the smoothness condition is omitted then any length will suffice (fold paper into an 'accordion' pattern, twist etc as detailed in this post: [Constructing a Möbius strip using a square paper? Is it possible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733922/constructing-a-m%C3%B6bius-strip-using-a-square-paper-is-it-possible))

I can show that using any rectangle of paper of length to width ratio greater than  $$\sqrt{3}:1$$

the construction in the picture can make a smooth non-self-intersecting Möbius Strip (with all the folds slightly rounded). In words you fold the strip along the lines drawn and the ends meet on the perpendicular of the equilateral triangle.I don't know whether this construction is optimal.

Is there a method to find the minimum ratio? Is there a general formula describing the minimum length of paper of width 1 unit needed to make a smooth non-intersecting paper band containing n half twists?

Comment: If you want the surface to satisfy the physical properties of paper, you want it to be not only [ruled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_surface) but also [developable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developable_surface).

Answer (score 3):

Richard Evan Schwartz, The optimal paper Moebius band, https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.12641 writes,

"In this paper we prove that a smooth embedded paper Moebius band must have aspect ratio greater than $\sqrt3.$ We also prove that any sequence of smooth embedded paper Moebius bands whose aspect ratio converges to $\sqrt3$ must converge, up to isometry, to the famous triangular Moebius band. These results answer the minimum aspect ratio question discussed by W. Wunderlich in 1962 and prove the more specific conjecture of B. Halpern and C. Weaver from 1977."

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem was just posed for BBC Radio 4 "Puzzle for Today" 652, so expect renewed interest (also a solution 14/01/20)! I found *by a process of trial and error* that a line of unit length, swept while twisting 180° around a circle radius 0.25 *appears* to be the minimum solution. A viewable (in genuine Adobe software) 3D PDF model can be found here: http://eyefidelity.co.uk/PFT652.pdf and I also include a screenshot of the plan view [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONvBS.png) which, intrigingly is **not quite** a cardioid (heavy black line). Sorry the calculus is beyond me but perhaps the empirical result may help another respondent

Comment: I expect this is not a developable surface and so cannot actually be constructed out of paper.

Comment: I agree … anyway here is a link to the BBC puzzle - and the published answer https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/4MV1T5lS89L46zldcySTP04/today-puzzle-652