# Is there a maximum width for a Möbius strip?

Tags: mobius-band

The Möbius strip is made by rotating one of the ends of a 2D strip 180° and then glueing  these together. I was wondering, how wide can the strip be? For example, can we still make a Möbius strip from a square? Making a Möbius strip by rotating the long sides of the strip seems impossible without stretching the strip.

And how will the strip look like if we let the width grow on "both" sides (of which there is actually one)?

Comment: Related questions have been asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733922/constructing-a-m%C3%B6bius-strip-using-a-square-paper-is-it-possible and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1262075/shortest-smooth-paper-m%C3%B6bius-strip, but not fully answered. There's a useful survey at https://www.nature.com/articles/nmat1929, freely available at https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucesgvd/moebius.pdf

Comment: There’s no principal limit - unless you intend to embed the Möbius strip in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: If you do, then this is an open problem.

Comment: Recently solved by Richard Evan Schwartz. See my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4794888